# Is event driven programming the same thing as asynchronous programming?

Tags: asynchronous, paradigms

The title says it all. I'm just wondering because I am trying to understand what asynchronous programming is and it seems similar to event driven programming I learned for swing and libgdx.

Comment: They're related, but not strictly a 1:1 relationship. async programming can use events, but that's just one way of getting things done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous programming is when you run `long running tasks` in the `background`, so that you don't have a blocking UI. Event driven programming is when the application in question is listening for events, say a user interaction or a notification to be received, and then a task is performed. They are not the same. There may be listeners for `user interactions` or `notifications`. That's a different issue.

Comment: Event driven doesn't requieres user interaction.